# wordpress customize - how to update a value?

Tags: php, wordpress, customization, custom-wordpress-pages

I have custom field(color picker) in my page. - http://take.ms/AejVS2

I want to update this value in wordpress customize field - http://take.ms/ezYJD

How can this be done with php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution **set_theme_mod()**